# android - TextView autoLink

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I want to show links in TextView and whenever user cliks the link, it must open.
xml Code:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web" />
```

Java Code:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Yes it's working and makes links blue and underline. But when I use a word for example **".hello"** it becomes a link because of dot. So If a dot and a word is adjoining, it becomes a link. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove linksClickable & autoLink attribute from xml

then you have to check that in given string is there any url available using regex.
Using Following Code :

```
private boolean containsURL(String content) {
    String REGEX = "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    if (m.find()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

if in given string contains url then it will be shown text in blue color.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Any String value");

if (containsURL("Any String value")) {
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    textView.setLinksClickable(true);
}
```